# Can't find any easy way to run Quake II on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, games, steam

I want to play Quake II. I did a install through Wine Steam, but it doesn't run and it actually crashes the whole computer!
I've been reading a few tutorials but they seem very complicated! And also they seems to always apply to install Quake II based on a Quake 2 CD Rom, never though Steam. Does anyone has any link or hint about where searching for this?

Also, if I manage to install it, will I be able to play it with my friends running it in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to askubuntu!

Great to hear that you feel you're getting comfortable using the terminal and Ubuntu. I'm pretty certain I speak for a vast majority of linux users when I say that if you can find the joy of exploring how thing works within linux, fixing stuff wont seem like such a chore anymore. Happy exploring and don't be afraid to play around with Ubuntu :-)

In regards to your question I can't really give you any guidance, without error messages and/or other terminal outputs. Try to run your game with your terminal environment through wine with `"wine quakeii.exe"` or equivalent. If you run `man wine` you will probably find a verbose option (maybe `-v`?). Try to invoke the verbose option if it exists and `"wine quakeii.exe"` doesn't yield any results, e.g. like this: `"wine quakeii.exe -v"`

The good news is that according to the appdb of WineHQ, Quake II should be runable on Ubuntu. Try to post the error messages on WineHQ, or in the IRC-channel #winehq on irc.freenode.net.

You could also check out PlayOnLinux which uses a modified version of Wine, which is optimized for certain games through user-patches and more. (I have never used PlayOnLinux myself, so I could be wrong here, but you should research it and find out if it's suitable for your situation)

Good luck

Comment: thank you for your answer. Actually I only could install Quake II through Steam via PlayOnLinux. I tried "wine quakeii.exe -v" but unfortunately I only received the following message "wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\quakeii.exe"". I'm trying to find where the game is installed in C: that PlayOnLinux created but with no success so far haha

Comment: Actually just found it, but I'm not sure I can guide the wine command through the folder it is in. I tried "wine c:\\users\\(myname) quakeii.exe -v" and it just returned "wine: Invalid handle."

Comment: Write "wine" (without the "") and drag the file into the terminal. Then the correct path should appear

Comment: Tried twice. Unfortunately it didn't work. No error messages in the terminal, just messages like the one I'll enter in the next comment.

A Wine Program Error Details was opened, but it's too long to me to post here.

Here's what happens:
after I hit enter with "Wine C:\\etcetcetcetct\\quakeii.exe -v", the game starts to load. Tons of things are quickly being loaded in the terminal. 

Eventually Steam is opened and almost imediatally everything lags for a few minutes. Then a Wine Error message appears.

Comment: err:ole:RevokeDragDrop invalid hwnd 0x100e0

fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification (handle=0xcafecafe), STUB!

fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification (handle=0xcafeaffe), STUB!

fixme:iphlpapi:CancelIPChangeNotify (overlapped 0x23d0510): stub

fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub

fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub

fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub

fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub

fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub

[2017-01-24 19:39:35] Shutdown

Comment: I can't really help you with that error ouput, unfortunately. I suggest you ask on their IRC-channel as I linked earlier. Redirect the output to a txt file. Do "wine yourpath_to_quakeii.exe -v > quakeii_output.txt". Find the .txt-file (probably in your home folder) and upload it to paste.ubuntu.com, and ask your question in the IRC-channel and link your paste. Did you try PlayOnLinux?